# Remove the possibility to send small file size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, email, uiactivityviewcontroller

guys.

I trying to share a gif with `UIActivityViewController`. I used code below:

```
NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:YES error:nil];
NSURL *fileURL = [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"animated.gif"];


NSString *text = @"This GIF was created successfully on Gifbooth https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gifbooth-free-gif-maker-animated/id1031899651?ls=1&mt=8";
NSData *gifFile=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileURL.path options:NSDataReadingMappedAlways error:nil];
UIActivityViewController *controller = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[text,gifFile] applicationActivities:nil];

[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

When i choose to share with email i got this.

[image]

I want remove the possibility to send the small file. I just want to send the file with real size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using default MAIL to send the image. You can not control the size of the images. Naturally you can present a very small image to mail, so that it will not come with a popup which image size to use.

Or send the image via another medium.